# Evaluation modules of $U_q(L(sl_2))$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups

Let $a \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, $r \in N$. Let $W = V_q(r)$ be the $r$-dimensional irreducible type 1 representation of $U_q(gl_2(\mathbb{C}))$. In the usual basis $\{v_0, \ldots, v_r\}$, the action of $U_q(gl_2(\mathbb{C}))$ on $V_q(r)$ is given by 
\begin{align}
& t_0.v_p = q^{(r-2p)/2} v_p, \\
& t_1.v_p = q^{-(r-2p)/2} v_p, \\
& x_1^+.v_p = [r-p+1]_q v_{p-1}, \\
& x_1^{-}.v_p = [p+1]_q v_{p+1}.
\end{align}

The evaluation module $V_q(r)_a$ is the pull-back of the module $
V_q(r)$ via the evaluation map $ev_a: U_q(L(sl_2)) \to U_q(gl_2)$.

On page 401, Example 12.2.11, of the book [a guide to quantum groups](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=bn5GNkLfnsAC&redir_esc=y), it is said that the Drinfeld polynomial associated to the evaluation module $V_q(r)_a$ is 
$$
P_1(u) = \prod_{p=1}^r(u - a^{-1} q^{2p-r-1}).
$$
How to compute this polynomial? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of this problem is given in [the paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104248585) by Chari and Pressley (the Corollary on Page 272).